# Open a HTML file in public folder in React project

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services

I have created an HTML file (ending with .html) inside the public folder in the reactJS package. This is what it currently looks like:

```
public/
    error/
         403.html
    index.html
```

I would like to reference the newly created file using the URL: `localhost:4321/error/403.html` this is what I would like to add in the AWS cloudfront for the domain testing. My question here is how do we access the newly created file?
When `localhost:4321` is loaded, it automatically loads index.html and when `localhost:4321/error/403.html` is given, I would like to load the 403.html file. Is that possible? Or do I have to look at other options like Routes?

Comment: Have you checked out [this CRA example](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)? (Assuming you are using Create React App)? Since you are using CloudFront, you could setup an S3 bucket with a behavior that points static files to it, or this specific file.

Answer (score 0):

No, don't use localhost. That will cause a nightmare. That's for **just you** to develop stuff. If you link to localhost, no one else will be able to access it. Make a file that is not on localhost and then link it there. As for your problem with filenames, you should include every necessary piece in the url. If you are using something other than project as your overarching directory, like:

```
project/
   public/
      error/
      403.html
```

Then you need to include `public/`. If it in the same directory as `index.html`, you need much less - write the path the same as you did for index.